# MutationObserver not firing on elements with role="grid"

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, mutation-observers

I'm attempting to carry out an accessibility fix on a table that has been poorly formatted using incorrect ARIA techniques.

To do this, I've written a MutationObserver to watch the page for instances of the table with role="grid" and dynamically change this to role="table", which addresses an accessibility issue when navigating the table with a screen reader.

I've been able to use the MutationObserver on other elements for this app (e.g., to fix incorrect use of aria-labelledby and role="group") and in those cases, I use the same logic and the MutationObserver executes the callback function and successfully changes the ARIA attributes. However, I can't understand why the MutationObserver is not identifying any role="grid" elements here when they appear in the DOM.

Here is my MutationObserver code:

```js
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    try {
        for (const mutation of mutationList) {
            if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
                if (mutation.attributeName === 'role') {
                    if (mutation.target.getAttribute('role') == 'grid') {
                        /* Replace ARIA role='grid' with role='table' */
                        mutation.target.setAttribute('role', 'table');
                        console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was changed`
                            + ` from ${mutation.target} to`
                            + ` ${mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)}`);
                    }
                }
            } else if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        if (node.hasAttribute('role')) {
                            if (node.getAttribute('role') == 'grid') {
                                /* Replace ARIA role='grid' with role='table' */
                                node.setAttribute('role', 'table');
                                console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was changed`
                                    + ` from ${mutation.target} to`
                                    + ` ${mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)}`);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
};



// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
    attributes: true,
    attributesOldValue: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

I can't directly copy the HTML source from the app because it's a proprietary app, but the structure of the role="grid" object looks like this:

```html
<div
  class="_xzy"
  role="grid"
  aria-rowcount="1"
  aria-colcount="11"
  id="HospitalityGrid"
  aria-multiselectable="true"
  aria-label="Hospitality"
  tabindex="0"
  style="height:
  250px; width: 720px;">
...
</div>
```

Just to anticipate any questions as to why I'm writing a MutationObserver to fix accessibility rather than requesting that the correct ARIA be implemented in the app itself, I don't have access to the source code or developers and so I'm writing this fix as an extension/add-in to make it more accessible to screen reader users.

To summarise, I tried writing a MutationObserver to automatically catch and fix elements with incorrect ARIA attribute role="grid". Currently nothing is happening as the role="grid" elements are not being identified by the MutationObserver callback function.

Comment: Maybe the element is inside shadow DOM? or in an iframe?

Comment: Is it possible that the div[role=grid] element was added to the page BEFORE your MutationObserver is registered? Even if the container is getting updated with new content, your code is only looking for the container to be added to the page.

Comment: @wOxxOm The element isn't inside an iframe. I haven't ever encountered a shadow DOM before, so that's an interesting suggestion - I'll have to do a bit of reading up on shadow DOMs and see whether that's the case here.

Comment: @Julianna no, the element is definitely not present on the page before the MutationObserver is registered. The MO is attached to the body element to ensure all elements are visible to the MO when the page updates. What is strange is that there are other elements on the page (e.g., role="group" and even some with role="grid") that are picked up by the MO and subsequently fixed by the callback, but just not the 3 instances of role="grid" that I'm specifically targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. While my MutationObserver was checking the added nodes, I wasn't checking the parent node (i.e., `mutation.target`). When I added an if statement to check the `mutation.target` node as well, my MutationObserver successfully registered the offending div element with `role='grid'` and changed it to `role='table'`.

```js
  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    try {
      for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          /* Examine parent node first */
          if (mutation.target.hasAttribute('role')) {
            if (mutation.target.getAttribute('role') === 'grid') {
                mutation.target.setAttribute('role', 'table');
                console.log(`The role attribute was changed from `
                  + `role='grid' to role='table'.`);
            }
          }
          /* Examine child/descendant nodes */
          for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
              if (node.hasAttribute('role')) {
                if (node.getAttribute('role') === 'grid') {
                  node.setAttribute('role', 'table');
                  console.log(`The role attribute was changed from `
                    + `role='grid' to role='table'.`);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch(e) {
     console.error(e.message);
    }
  };

  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const targetNode = document.getElementById('mainContainer');

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    attributesOldValue: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  
  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```